# JQuery .html function

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery .get to load the contents of a page. The page loads okay and the ouput is stored in a variable data. I only want to grab a specific div with the id of 'result1' out of that data variable and place it on the page. I am having trouble parsing this specific element from the variable data, it seems that all elements are being placed on the page. I think this is an easy fix but its driving me crazy.

Here is the base code without any parsing attempts:

```
$.get("test.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&auth=1" ,function(data){
        $("#details1").html(data);
  });
```

Here is the results of data:

```
<div id='result1'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>testa</td>
<td>testb</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id='result2'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>testc</td>
<td>testd</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply use `.load` and pass a selector. http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Try http://api.jquery.com/load/. See the "Loading Page Fragments" section.

Comment: I cannot use load given the nature of the code. I have to parse this data variable for specific elements.

Comment: Yes, you can, because `.load()` specifically allows you to select parts of the returned HTML.

Comment: Please explain what about load() you cannot use.

Comment: I I have to make one http request and load three divs from that request into three different elements. I was originally using load but that limited me to loading data from 1 or more divs into a single div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#details1").load("test.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&auth=1 #result1");
```

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

or you can do the same yourself:

```
$.get("test.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&auth=1" ,function(data){
    $("#details1").append( $('<div />').append(data).find('#result1') );
    $("#details2").append( $('<div />').append(data).find('#result2') );
    $("#details3").append( $('<div />').append(data).find('#result3') );
});
```

Comment: What if I wanted to load result1 into a element details1 and result2 into an element details2 in a single http request?

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to load only the `result1` div in the `details1` element.

```
$('#details1').load("test.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&auth=1 #result1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("test.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&auth=1" ,function(data){
    $("#details1").html($(data).filter('#result1'));
});
```